# Wordpress Cherry frame work migrate server

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less, migrate

I am trying to migrate the site with cherry frame work and bootstrap to another server. I am using Wp-migrate-db plugin to change the urls in database. After moving files and restoring the database to new server i am clearing the .cache files for less. But in the new site the styling is being lost. Can anybody let me know step by step to move this site?

Comment: On-line tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUxCZTWyFWk